# HTACCESS short URL to subdomain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

**Hi,**

I want to redirect domain.com/1/ to sub.domain.com/1/ but I dont want to redirect all trafic to domain.com to sub.domain.com.

*What is the best way to do this?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file of `domain.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^1/?$ http://sub.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```